# Use separate Application Insights for error logging and user analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are planning on using Azure Application Insights for our web app. It has been suggested that we use two instances: one for error logging and the other for user analytics. While these are different needs, it seems like one instance can accommodate both needs. What is best practice?

Comment: What was the reason behind the suggestion? I can think of none.

Comment: A few potential: there are different teams looking at the data, the UI team for user analytics and the dev team for errors. Also, the logging. might include the User ID while the analytics are anonymous. I realize these can be handled in the way the log messages are created but this was part of the rationale.

Comment: Create seperate workbooks then, and then use RBAC to give devs access to all and ui team to some workbooks. I think it  will take some effort to split the telemetry between seperate resources because our of the box that is not supported when using the SDKs

Comment: @rsalit, are you referring that backend service to push data to one Application Insights resource and web client side to push data to another? If yes then many customers do have separate resources. If you are referring that data from the same app goes to different AI resources then though you can implement it this way it is an advanced scenario.

Comment: @ZakiMa We already have separate App Insights for the front and back end. What was proposed was to have two for the front end. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[I'm from Application Insights team]

The best practice is that telemetry from one app should go to the same Application Insights resource.

There might be advanced (and rare) scenarios (for instance, one stream represents audit log and should be retained way longer and / or have different RBAC requirements) where it makes sense to send to different Application Insights resources.

Comment: And how would do implement this in practise? Our project has the exact same needs as above.

Comment: @softbear, it depends on the language you use. For instance, in .NET you can create separate telemetry client and provide different Connection String. This should be sufficient to send data to different Application Insights resources.